# How to pass comma character in makefile function

Tags: shell, makefile

In Makefile there is defined a `print` function, which takes print text as argument and then print it.
My question is that how to pass comma character as a text part to print it ?
For example below is relevant makefile section where comma is not printable.

```
print = echo '$(1)'

help:
        @$(call print, He lives in Paris, does not he?)
```

Now if run makefile like:

```
$ make help
```

It prints

```
$  He lives in Paris
```

instead of

```
$  He lives in Paris, does not he?
```

I know in makefile comma uses as argument separate, but how I can make it as printable.
I used different escape character combination to pass comma as text message like `\,` `/,` `$$,` `','` `","`  but nothing works

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html#Syntax-of-Functions#:~:text=Commas%20and%20unmatched%20parentheses) says:

> Commas and unmatched parentheses or braces cannot appear in the text of an argument as written; leading spaces cannot appear in the text of the first argument as written. These characters can be put into the argument value by variable substitution.

So, you need to put comma into a variable, and use it in the argument. E.g:

```
print = echo '$(1)'
comma:= ,

help:
        @$(call print,He lives in Paris$(comma) does not he?)
```

Answer (score 4):

Same as the [answer of oguz ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806103/502236), but with slight optimization:

- You can use a comma itself as a variable name

```
, := ,
msg = echo '$1'
help:; @$(call msg,He lives in Paris$(,) does not he?)
```

[Source](https://blog.jgc.org/2007/06/escaping-comma-and-space-in-gnu-make.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
print = echo '$(1)' | sed 's/(\(.*\))/\1/'

help:
        @$(call print, (He lives in Paris, does not he?))
```

Output becomes:

```
$ make help
 He lives in Paris, does not he?
```

You have to tweak the regex in `sed` if you include parenthesis in your string.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to have parenthesis inside the argument you can use a more elaborate sed script to strip the parenthesis.

```
define print 
        echo "`echo \"$(1)\" | sed -e 's/^(\|)$$//g'`";
endef

help:
        @$(call print,(He lives in Paris, does not he? in a (house) with parenthesis inside))
```

Basically you are supposed to change $(1) with `echo \"$(1)\" | sed -e 's/^(\|)$$//g'`.

Disclaimer: This is from a blog of mine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thank you for your answer. Please, remove your link or people may flag this as span. More on the policy: https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion